# How to solve the error of "[_NSCFTimer login:]:unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created an application. When I run my application I get the following error:

```
-[__NSCFTimer login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b37380
2011-04-12 10:57:36.441 Journey[6190:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b37380'.
```

How can I solve the above mentioned error?

Comment: it seems that you are calling a method on wrong instance. Would you plz provide some code?

Comment: NSTimer does not have a method login. Hence the error. Pls provide some code so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `login` method on  the instance of `NSTimer` ?

If yes, you can't, you could only call methods on  the instance of `NSTimer` those declared in NSTimer class

See the apple documentation for `NSTimer`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

Under Build Settings, add "-ObjC" to the "Other Linker Flags" section.

The reference:
[Error when try to start scanning chromecast device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693171/error-when-try-to-start-scanning-chromecast-device)