# Error when try to start scanning chromecast device

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Working with iOS:  I got this error when trying to call `startScan` method of a `GCKDeviceScanner` instance.

Any suggestions?

```
2014-03-27 11:03:17.814 XXX4Cast[3542:60b] -[__NSCFTimer gck_setTolerance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc8260
2014-03-27 11:03:17.818 XXX4Cast[3542:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer gck_setTolerance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc8260'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer:

Under Build Settings, add "-ObjC" to the "Other Linker Flags" section.

Comment: I added this but still received the exception... is there any other solution?